# LWC No re-render after getting iframe value

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, postmessage

I want to pass the parameters of the `iframe` to the LWC page.

After the LWC receives the parameters, the `Save` button cancels the disabled,

**Result** I found that isDisabled is equal to false, but the button is not clickable.
[image]

**Desired result** The button is clickable.

LWC HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-box">
        <iframe src="https://brp-tpservice.yhcrm.cn/testPage.html" height="200" width="500"></iframe>
    </div>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="LastName" ></lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleSuccess} disabled={isDisabled}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

LWC JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class demo extends LightningElement {
    siteurl;
    @track isDisabled = true;
    @track newObject = {};

    renderedCallback(){
        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            console.log('renderedCallback');
            // Handle the message
            console.log(event.data);
            this.isDisabled = false;
            console.log( 'isDisabled = ' + this.isDisabled);
        }, false);
    }

    handleVFResponse(message) {
        console.log('connectedCallback => ' + JSON.stringify(message));
        if (!message.data) {
            this.isDisabled = false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Post Message</h1>


<input id="numb">
<input id="phone">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var lexOrigin = "https://frensworkz43-dev-ed.lightning.force.com";

function myFunction() {
    console.log('= myFunction = ');
    let message1 = 'testing';
    let message2 = 'testing';
    window.parent.postMessage(message1, '*');
    window.parent.postMessage(message2, 'https://frensworkz43-dev-ed.lightning.force.com');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Send Successfully';
}


window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // if (event.origin !== lexOrigin) return;
    console.log('Origin '+ event.origin);
    console.log('data '+ event.data);
    if (data) {
        myFunction();
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `renderedCallback` you defined a function with `function` keyword, this way that function has its own `this` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#no_separate_this)

> Until arrow functions, **every new function defined its own this value** (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming.

So `this.isDisabled` inside that function doesn't refer to the `isDisabled` property of your class.

In order to fix it you should use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#arrow_functions), which does not have its own `this`, but inherit the `this` of the enclosing execution contex.

```js
renderedCallback(){
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        console.log('renderedCallback');
        // Handle the message
        console.log(event.data);
        this.isDisabled = false;
        console.log('isDisabled = ', this.isDisabled);
    }, false);
}
```

Another way to fix the issue is calling [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method on your function:

```js
renderedCallback(){
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
        console.log('renderedCallback');
        // Handle the message
        console.log(event.data);
        this.isDisabled = false;
        console.log( 'isDisabled = ' + this.isDisabled);
    }.bind(this), false);
}
```